# Logitech C615 web cam sound control

Tags: audio, webcam

I have a Logitech C615 web cam with a built-in microphone. I want to use a headset with earplugs and a microphone for more private conversations. There are phone out and mic in plugs on my Mac Mini.

However, I can not turn the sound off on the web cam. I can mute it, but the headset mic will not work.

Is there a way to turn off the sound on the web cam, or do I need to buy another one without the mic?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change which device is used for audio input. Just hold down <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> while clicking on the Volume menu item:
[image]

Alternatively, to get a bit more fine control, open System Preferences (found under  > System Preferences…) and open the Sound preference pane:

[image]

Comment: I added the Sound pane in System Preferences. Hope that's all right by you. :)